# How to access values inside a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

My nested dictionary looks like this:

```py
{'access': {'product': 0, 'phone': 15}, '4.5%': {'product': 0, 'phone': 1}, 'growth': {'product': 0, 'phone': 3}}
```

I have to calculate the log likely score of a word occurring with product or phone, for example for the word access:

p1= (number of time product occurred with access) / total number of products in all of file

p2= (number of time phone occurred with access) / total number of products in all of file

log likely score = p1/p2 --> which I then have to put into another dictionary with the word it corresponds to for example {access: log likely score, 4.5: log likely score}

I already have the total number of product and phone in all of the file.

My question is, how would I access the number associated with product and phone for each word within the dictionary? In this example for the word "access", product occurs 0 times and phone occurs 15. How would I access 0 and 15 (and do so for the rest of the words as well)?

Update with things I have tried:

```py
for key,value in d:
        product = value["product"]
        phone = value["phone"]
        print(key,product,phone)
```

^This gets me the error that there are too many things to unpack

```py
for i in d.values():
        print(i)
        for j in d[i].values():
            print(j)
```

^This gets me the error: unhashable type: `dict`

```
for key,value in d.items():
        print("Key: ",key) #Key: access
        print("Value: ", value) #Value: {'product': 0, 'phone': 15}
```

^ I have tried this and it works, but I am having trouble getting the value 0 and 15.

Comment: You access each level in turn, just as you would do with a nested list.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Updated with things I have tried!

Comment: Did you mean: `for key,value in d.items():`?

Comment: Yes, I also just tried this: for key,value in d.items():
        print("Key: ",key) #Key: access
        print("Value: ", value) #Value: {'product': 0, 'phone': 15}
Which works, but I need to get the individual value for product and phone within the value variable.

Comment: products_count = 20
result_dict = {word:test_dict[word]['phone']/products_count for word in test_dict.keys()}

Answer (score 0):

The syntax goes like this:

`dict['access']['product']`

or:

`dict.get('access').get('product')`

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'access': {'product': 0, 'phone': 15}, '4.5%': {'product': 0, 'phone': 1}, 'growth': {'product': 0, 'phone': 3}}
print(dictionary['access']['phone']) # prints 15
```